# Re-Meshing ("use output of meshgrid in order to create new meshgrid")

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

say I have three grids,

```
a = arange(0,5)
b = arange(0,3)
c = arange(10,12)
```

And for some reason, in my code, I first need to mesh

```
A, B = meshgrid(a,b,indexing='ij')
```

Is there a short way in which I could do

```
A, B, C = remeshgrid(A, B, c, indexing='ij)
```

such that `A`, `B`, `C` all correspond to meshgrid(a,b,c, indexing='ij')?

The scenario is the following. 
 - I first have a, b and mesh A, B
 - Later on, I generate c
 - At this point, I need to remesh everything containing c. But the code does not have a,b at disposal anymore.

So now it's a tradeoff of adjusting code in order to pass over a, b - if remeshing A,B is not possible or too inefficient.

Do you guys have any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

Building on Davidmh's idea, you could use `A[:,0]` and `B[0,:]`. This will work even if `A` or `B` contains duplicate values; and taking a slice is faster than calling `np.unique`.

```
In [71]: A[:,0]
Out[71]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

In [72]: B[0,:]
Out[72]: array([0, 1, 2])

In [73]: A, B, C = np.meshgrid(A[:,0], B[0,:], c, indexing='ij')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reconstruct `a` and `b` taking the unique elements:

```
print A
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4]])

print B
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2]])

np.unique(A)
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

np.unique(B)
array([0, 1, 2])
```